# Json with null value deserialize issue

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to deserialize below json with the first value equal to null, into simple array with doubles. However I am getting error `The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<double[]>(string, params Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter[])' has some invalid arguments`

```
{[
  null,
  0.1,
  0.2,
  0.3
]}
```

The code is

```
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<double[]>(valJson, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
   NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
   MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
});
```

I have tried multiple configurations i.e. NullValueHandling.Include without any success. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: 1) 2)  Why not just deserialize to `List<double?>` and filter afterwards?  2) Your JSON is malformed.  It should not have the outer braces `{ }`.  That might just be due to Visual Studio "helpfully" visualizing the JSON for you, so can you confirm the braces are not present by checking the raw JSON?

Comment: By the way, I tried to reproduce your problem but I am not getting the compilation error you are seeing.  Instead I am getting a runtime error *`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Double'. Path '[0]', line 2, position 6.`*.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/8WJn2d.  Is `valJson` really a string, or is it a `JArray`?

Comment: Demo of filtering here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6SIDvc.  Is that all you want?  If not, see [Json.Net: How to ignore null elements in array deserializing a JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62940751/3744182), of which your question may be a duplicate; agree?

Answer (score 2):

just instead of double use double?, It was tested in Visual Studio, no any problem at all, everything is working properly.

```
double?[] d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<double?[]>(json);
```

Comment: I am afraid this does not solve the issue. Still the same erro as in the description.

Comment: @Jim I tested it before posting. No any issues.